# Math behind sorting grade percentages for grade forecast

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, mathematical-optimization, modular-arithmetic

Title looks weird but I'll try to elaborate as much as I can.

I want to write a program which is able to provide me the percentages I need to get all possible grades in the class (A,B,C; A = max 10 points lost, B = max 20 points lost, C = max 30 points lost).

So right now my problem is how should I distribute the amounts of points I can lose, given say I can get a B grade but only can have 12% distributed between 4 homework(each of 1%) and final of 40%.

Is it better to use something of modular arithmetic? (let n=12, then n% 12 to 6 gives all possible combination of scores). This may also be easy when I have more than 2 criteria (homework, midterm, final, project etc)

or

just do some loop/iteration through the total percentage that can be lost?

```
eg 12 - 1
   12 - 2
   ....
   12 - 11
   12 - 12
```

Please provide me with some ideas to implement the modular arithmetic version but my understanding of it is not superb.

On the other hand, if there's a better algorithm or way to do so, feel free to tell me!

Comment: So you didn't implement anything? leave better not even a *worst* one?

Comment: @s_vishnu not yet, I know I'm suppose to start with a trashy version, but i was thinking about the math behind it and also the math behind all possible grades for each criteria that will give all the possible overall grades (n^k, where n is the number of grades and k is the number of criteria)

but then i realize it's not a very good thing(or idea) to do, redundancy and like you imply I want to do a working program of my idea, so that can wait

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Give us a *complete* example, with a clear explanation of what the input parameters are, and what the expected outputs are.

Comment: @jim my question here as stated in the last sentence is if using modulo to find the pairs that sum to a certain number e.g 12 is more efficient than brute force. No code involved, probably time complexity

Comment: Try this: assume we know nothing about the problem you're trying to solve. Because, even after your edit and your comment, it's still not obvious. Explain the problem to us, *without* mentioning what you think the solution might be. *Then*, give us a complete example, again without mentioning how you think you'd implement code. Without a clear explanation of what you're trying to do, we can't help you.